# How to save an XML file without adding line-breaks between empty open and close tags?

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, infopath

Schema validation found non-datatype errors.

I read the manual and it mentioned this is due to external list database has a. The field marked as non-nullable.
b. The field can accept empty strings as valid input.

In my case below, the Sum is required, but the other five fields are not.

XmlDocument.Save(pathToFile) sucessfully saves the document with the desired changes, but then the schema becomes invalid when attempting to open the InfoPath from in SharePoint.

I compared the original format to the updated format. All empty nodes have a line break after the save. A line by line review of the original text to the updated text did not reveal any other changes. I can copy the original text back into the updated file, manually add the changes to my:Sum, and the form then loads as expected.

After the save I can see the data in the SP list items as expected: I just can't open the item in InfoPath.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] xmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\path\to\files");

    foreach(string fileName in xmlFiles)
    {

        FileInfo theFile = new FileInfo(fileName);

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        using(FileStream fs = theFile.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            xml.Load(fs);
        }

        XPathNavigator navigator = xml.CreateNavigator();

        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2017-04-19T15:13:18");

        List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> List2 = new List<string>();
        List<string> List3 = new List<string>();
        List<string> List4 = new List<string>();
        List<string> List5 = new List<string>();

        foreach(XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//my:Field1", manager))
        {
            List1.Add(nav.Value);
        } /*repeated for all five lists*/

        int i = 0;
        decimal currentSum = Decimal.Zero;
        foreach(XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//my:Sum", manager))
        {
            currentSum = Decimal.Zero;
            currentSum += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(List1[i]) ? Decimal.Zero : Convert.ToDecimal(List1[i]); /*repeated for all 5 lists*/

            nav.SetValue(currentSum.ToString());
            i++;
        }

        xml.Save(fileName);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Original - no line breaks in empty nodes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<three more lines of infopath generated headers>
<my:myFields>
    <my:Details>
        <my:Field1>1</my:Field1>
        <my:Field2>2</my:Field2>
        <my:Field3>3</my:Field3>
        <my:Field4>4</my:Field4>
        <my:Field5 xsi:nil="true"></my:Field5>
        <my:Sum>0</my:Sum>
    </my:Details>
    <my:Details>
        <my:Field1 xsi:nil="true"></my:Field1>
        <my:Field2>2</my:Field2>
        <my:Field3>3</my:Field3>
        <my:Field4>4</my:Field4>
        <my:Field5 xsi:nil="true"></my:Field5>
        <my:Sum>0</my:Sum>
    </my:Details>
</my:myFields>
```

Updated - line breaks in all empty nodes whether marked nil or not.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<three more lines of infopath generated headers>
<my:myFields>
    <my:Details>
        <my:Field1>1</my:Field1>
        <my:Field2>2</my:Field2>
        <my:Field3>3</my:Field3>
        <my:Field4>4</my:Field4>
        <my:Field5 xsi:nil="true">
        </my:Field5>
        <my:Sum>10</my:Sum>
    </my:Details>
    <my:Details>
        <my:Field1 xsi:nil="true">
        </my:Field1>
        <my:Field2>2</my:Field2>
        <my:Field3>3</my:Field3>
        <my:Field4>4</my:Field4>
        <my:Field5 xsi:nil="true">
        </my:Field5>
        <my:Sum>9</my:Sum>
    </my:Details>
</my:myFields>
```

Comment: A conformant parser won't care. Why do you?

Comment: @madreflection because InfoPath throws a schema validation error when the line breaks are present.

Comment: @Dave, I would recommend to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework for more than 10 years.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thank you. I rewrote the code to use XDoc and use XElement form Linq to XML and it does not add the spaces that XmlDoc added on its save.

Comment: @Dave, glad to hear that the LINQ to XML API is working for you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's available on .NET and there might be a simpler way, but one option would be to replace the "Save" with a null XSLT transformation: put it through a stylesheet that simply has:

```
<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
```

Microsoft XML tools seem to be generally a bit cavalier about adding or removing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

When emptying the tag set the specific flag word to empty it.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)){ text = "need_to_be_blank";}
GetRootNode(Xpath).CurrentNode.InnerText = text;
```

then after saving it , replace all flag word to ""

```
_xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
string readText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, readText.Replace("need_to_be_blank",""));
```